# Weird ^M characters on my script file

Tags: bash, editor, text-editor

I have a script that is not working. I get this message when executing it:

This is the file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# import tv tipps (a.o.)
/usr/local/bin/php_cli /html/typo3/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase import:runalljobs
```

and this is what I get when I run it:

```
-bash: ./import_tvtips.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

I get this "^M" weird character that I can't see in the editor. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have ^M extra character(s) in your script import_tvtips.sh. Remove them and your script should execute.

Comment: Look, copy&pase of my file. No extra characters: http://nopaste.info/cf2e915955_nl.html

Comment: please `cat -v import_tvtips.sh` to be extra sure :)

Comment: Oh damm! Its there!! Why cant I see it in my editor?! :O how can I remove it?

Comment: my prefered one: `sed -i -e 's/\r//g' yourfile`  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix