# Shell command to strip out ^M characters from text file

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove carriage return in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix)

I am reading some data generated by an external third party. I have noticed that the ASCII text in the file is interspersed with ^M characters, which I believe is character 13 in ASCII and represents a carriage return without linefeed.

Is there a one liner I can use to strip the ^M characters from the file?

I am running on Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use sed like this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^M$//' infile.txt
```

To type `^M`, you need to type `CTRL-V` and then `CTRL-M`.

Comment: Thank you. This is all I needed. I am guessing that infile.txt is the file to be cleansed ?, not sure what i.bak is though, perhaps, I'll go look in the manual, unless you are gracious enough to explain ..?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: You're most welcome. `-i` flag in sed is used for inline editing of a file and `-i.bak` is used for saving the original input file with `.bak` extension for safety measure.

Comment: The `-i.bak` is a GNU `sed` extension that means 'do in-place alter of the file, backing up the original with the `.bak` extension'.  Reading the manual is still a good idea, though.

Answer (score 9):

OR

```
dos2unix infile.txt file2.txt ....
```

OR

```
man dos2unix
```

for more details.

Comment: dos2unix works if it is available but unfortunately it is not available to all flavors of Unix/Linux.

Comment: I only have experience with RH linux, but I thought all versions of Linux had `dos2unix` (Lots of old-line unix experience!). As the user specified Linux I think its a useful suggestion. Not all `sed`s support `-i` after all ;-). Thanks and good luck to all.

Comment: eg dos2unix isn't available on my Mac and if you note `-i` is optional in my answer. A simple `sed 's/^M$//' infile.txt > output.txt` should also work.

Comment: I don't see that `-i` is optional in your answer. Not looking for a fight. Just to recognize that in unix too, there's more than one way to do it ;-> . Good luck to all.

Comment: It is obvious that text replacement in sed is being handled by `'s/^M$//'` and `-i` is just an optional and convenient shortcut.

Comment: dos2unix now available on macOS...