# how to show ^M char in gedit (redhat)?

Tags: gedit

When I open file using cat command in terminal then '^M' this symbol is shown but in gedit this symbol is not visible.How to shown on gedit or how to remove?

Comment: It's a carriage return -- check gedit for whitespace options (the new gedit seems much worse in the options regard, though) -- ([maybe this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162851/option-to-display-control-characters-in-gedit)).  See [this related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589895/shell-command-to-strip-out-m-characters-from-text-file) for information about how to strip them out.

Comment: Is any option in gedit for encoding text?

Comment: It depends on the gedit version.  Older ones definitely had this option.  But this question may be better suited for SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

`^M`, as noted in the comments, is the carriage-return character. Instead of looking for a way to make gefit display them just so you could remove them manually, it may be easier to use dos2unix:

```
$ dos2unix myfile.txt
```