# How to add ending square brackets in awk

Tags: awk

I want to enclose each line of my input in square brackets. I am able to add the beginning square bracket. But not the ending one. The ending "]" goes to the next line and clips the line.

e.g. - Here is my script -

```
cat file.csv | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} {print $1,"["$6,$7"]"}'
```

The op is - ]ABC,[CD,EF

Thanks

Comment: The awk is correct, it's the file that is the problem like @paxdiablo says, run `dos2unix file.csv` to sort out the line ending issue. Sidenote: drop the [UUoC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this may be a line-ending issue, as in your lines are terminated with `CR/LF` (carriage return and line feed) rather than just `LF` on its own. What's *actually* being output is:

```
ABC,[CD,EF<CR>]
```

and the `CR` is forcing the cursor back to the start of the line before outputting the final `]` character.

You can see a similar effect with:

```
pax> awk -v x='abcdef^M' 'END {print "123 ["x"]"}' </dev/null
]23 [abcdef
```

where the `^M` is actually a `CR` character, input with `CTRL-V`, `CTRL-M`.

As to how to fix it, you can either fix the file itself to get rid of the dodgy line endings, or you can use something like `gsub` on the final field of the line to get rid of `CR` characters:

```
pax> # this bit here ----------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
pax> awk -v x='abcdef^M' 'END {gsub("^M","",x);print "123 ["x"]"}' </dev/null
123 [abcdef]
```

In your case, that would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} {gsub("^M","",$7);print $1,"["$6,$7"]"}' file.csv
```

noting that `cat file.csv |` is totally unnecessary here since `awk` is perfectly capable of processing file names itself. Myself, I'd prefer fixing the file if that's at all possible.

Fow a multitude of ways to fix said file (depending on what tools you have available to you), see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix/800644#800644).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works with proper input, example:

```
$ echo {A..J} | sed 's/ /,/g' | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} {print $1,"["$6,$7"]"}'
A,[F,G]
```

as the migthy @paxdiablo says, probably a line-ending issue. Check with the [`file`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file)-command

To convert to *proper* line-endings use e.g. [`fromdos`](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/fromdos) or `dos2unix`