# Remove %0D from variable in BASH

Tags: bash, wget

I'm trying this:

```
token=`curl -I --header "X-Auth-User: user@user.com" --header "X-Auth-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" api.server.com | grep -Fi X-Auth-Token | awk -F" " '{ print $2}'`

/usr/bin/wget --accept .jpg,.jpeg -p "https://api.server.com/v1/stats/1/graph?callback=jQuery171027000000144289315_1380000003353&mnum=1&res_type=cpu&g_type=6h&graph_type=img&full=1&w=515&h=150&X-Auth-Token=$token" -O "image.jpg" || rm "image.jpg"
```

But my token result is:

```
https://api.server.com/v1/stats/1/graph?callback=jQuery171027000000144289315_1380000003353&mnum=1&res_type=cpu&g_type=6h&graph_type=img&full=1&w=515&h=150&X-Auth-Token=SERVER_018d8100000000001d1b817f7d58a6%0D
```

Instead of:

```
https://api.server.com/v1/stats/1/graph?callback=jQuery171027000000144289315_1380000003353&mnum=1&res_type=cpu&g_type=6h&graph_type=img&full=1&w=515&h=150&X-Auth-Token=SERVER_018d8100000000001d1b817f7d58a6
```

How to remove %0D (Carriage return)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can add `| tr -d '\r'` to your curl pipeline to strip any carriage returns.

Comment: The way I read this, it's the sending server which tacks on a URL-encoded carriage return. So there is no client-side CR to trim.

Comment: @tripleee The carriage return is carried from the curl HEAD response into the url, and wget url encodes it. You can see both effects with `curl -I google.com | cat -v` and `wget $'http://google.com/\r'`

Comment: More info about TR here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/tr.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility called dos2unix. You may have to install it. or use the translate

```
tr -d '\r' < input > output
```

EDIT
Found a post that discusses a few options:
[Remove carriage return in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by piping to `sed`. I was already using `sed` in my pipe so it made sense.

`cmd | sed 's/\r//g'`