# using -i and -O in same time when using wget

Tags: linux, bash, wget

i have a txt file which contains url of files
and name of the files are same

```
https://example.com/asdf/a.jpg
https://example.com/njff/a.jpg
https://example.com/8ikd/a.jpg
https://example.com/98ik/a.jpg
https://example.com/90uo/a.jpg
```

and i want to download those files with different names like this

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
```

i tried using bash while loop and -O to change name of files, but %0D is at end of url

```
https://example.com/90uo/a.jpg%0D
```

My question is, how can i remove %0D? or is there any way to download from urls which has same file name and rename them not to be duplicated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185095/remove-0d-from-variable-in-bash ? Or `dos2unix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wget -c --output-document - https://example.com/asdf/a.jpg > 1.jpg
```

--output-document flag tells wget to perform shell redirection other than instructing it to use the new name instead of the original name in the URL