# Printing Nth line of file acting strangely with text files from Windows

Tags: bash, shell, plaintext

I have two files, both of which appear to my eyes as follows.

```
a

a
```

The difference is that I created one of them with `vim` and the other with the wine version of Notepad. I wrote the following script to print each line of these files at a time, more or less emulating `cat` (That's not my end goal, of course, but it's the simplest example I've thought of.).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t list_file < "$1"

for line in "${list_file[@]}"
do
        echo "line content: \"$line\""
done
```

Expectedly, with the file created by `vim` (5 bytes as expected: `a[newline][newline]a[newline]`) as `$1`, it outputs this.

```
line content: "a"
line content: ""
line content: "a"
```

Unexpectedly, with the file created by Notepad (It's 6 bytes; I'm not sure why.) as `$1`, it outputs this. Why does it do this?

```
"ine content: "a
"ine content: "
line content: "a"
```

I also tried doing this completely differently, but the following script has *exactly* the same problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for line_number in $(eval echo {1..$(wc -l < "$1")})
do
  echo "line content: $(sed -n "${line_number}p" "$1")"
done
```

What is the matter with these scripts that causes them to behave like this with the Notepad-created file?

Comment: Use the `file` command to find out what type of line-endings a text file contains, and the `dos2unix` command to strip the CR characters from a CRLF file.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix) has relevant information, particularly `tr -d '\r' < infile > outfile`. That seems like less hassle than having to install `dos2unix`.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file created by `vim` has lines ending with `LF`, as on Unix. The file created with `Notepad` has lines ending with `CR LF`, as on DOS/Windows. `bash` uses `LF` as its line delimiter, so when it reads from the second file it leaves the `CR` at the end of each line. When you echo this character, it causes the cursor to return to the left margin, without advancing to the next line.