# Reading Trace file from NS2 using gawk

Tags: awk, gawk, ns2

I am new user of gawk. I am trying to read trace file by putting a small code in a file and then by making that file executable. Following is what I am trying to do.

```
#!/bin/sh 
set i = 0 
while ($i < 5) 
awk 'int($2)=='$i' && $1=="r"  && $4==0 {pkt += $6} END {print '$i'":"pkt}'  out.tr 
set i = `expr $i + 1` 
end
```

after this I am running following command:

```
sh ./test.sh
```

and it says:

```
syntax error: word unexpected (expecting do)
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash`

Syntax of `while` loop:

```
while test-commands; do consequent-commands; done
```

[more info](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html)

For comparison using `<` operator you need to use Double-Parentheses see [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) and [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs).

To assign value to the variable you used in the code just write `i=0`.

To access a shell variable in `awk` use `-v` option of `awk`.

Thus your might be become like this:

```
i=0 
while ((i < 5))
do
  awk -v k=$i 'int($2)==k && $1=="r"  && $4==0 {pkt += $6} END {print k":"pkt}'  out.tr 
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Here the variable `k` in `awk` code, has the value of variable `$i` from shell.
Instead of `expr $i + 1` you can use `$((i + 1))` or shorter `$((++i))`

Also you can use `for` loop then your code becomes much cleaner:

```
for (( i=0; i < 5; i++ ))
do
  awk -v k=$i 'int($2)==k && $1=="r"  && $4==0 {pkt += $6} END {print k":"pkt}'  out.tr 
done
```

Comment: Tried both in the first case still gives me the same error. In the second case of FOR loop. it says:

    Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Comment: @user3196876, Is your shell `bash`? the output of `readlink  /bin/sh`

Comment: I dont know I am using Ubuntu 12.04 I think its shell is bash. I am running following command:

sh ./test.sh

Comment: @user3196876, What is the output of `readlink  /bin/sh`? However you can try to change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` in your code and use `bash ./test.sh`.

Comment: tried #!/bin/bash  with  bash ./test.sh and it is throwing more errors now. The output of readlink /bin/sh is dash

Comment: @user3196876, in your ubuntu `sh` is linked to `dash`, thus when you use `sh ./test.sh` the file is executed with `dash`. but it should not  have problems with `bash`, it is working for me. Anyways, what are the errors when you try to run the file with `bash`?

Comment: ./test.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'/test.sh: line 3: `for (( i=0; i < 5; i++ ))

Comment: @user3196876,It is caused by `\r` you can use `dos2unix` to remove it, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix)