# Bash script variable output not working

Tags: linux, bash, echo, sh

I have a bash script that is parsing files containing information about processes running on a server. Everything works except the output.

Target output

`tomcat7    Running    Monitored   3025   18d 2h 16m   3.6%   0.0%`

What it actually is outputing

`0.0%2h 16m ing`

Script portion doing the parsing and output

```
for SERVER in $SERVERS ; do
    SYSTEM=$(sed -n '/System/{p; n;p; n;p; n;p; n;p; n;p}' $H_DIR/$SERVER.txt)
    sed -n '/Process/{p; n;p; n;p; n;p; n; n;p; n;n;n; n;p; n; n;p}' $H_DIR/$SERVER.txt > $H_DIR/procs.txt
    split --lines=7 $H_DIR/procs.txt $H_DIR/procs.txt.
    for PROC in $H_DIR/procs.txt.?? ; do
        PROCESS=$(cat $PROC | head -1 | tail -1 | cut -d "'" -f2)
        STATUS=$(cat $PROC | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $NF }')
        MONITOR=$(cat $PROC | head -3 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $NF }')
        PID=$(cat $PROC | head -4 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $NF }')
        UPTIME=$(cat $PROC | head -5 | tail -1 | awk '{ print substr($0, index($0, $2)) }')
        PCPU=$(cat $PROC | head -6 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $NF }')
        PMEM=$(cat $PROC | head -7 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $NF }')
        echo $PROCESS $STATUS $MONITOR $PID $UPTIME $PCPU $PMEM
    done
    rm -f $H_DIR/procs.*
    rm -f $H_DIR/$SERVER.txt
done
```

raw file being parse

```
Process 'tomcat7'
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  pid                               3025
  uptime                            18d 2h 30m
  memory percent                    3.6%
  cpu percent                       0.0%
```

Comment: Your sample file and output indicate that you're only printing the last element from each line. Why kill yourself? take out all of that stuff and experment with `echo "$procInfo" | awk '{printf $NF}:END{print ""}'` .. How you get proc info should also be simple. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : where did $procInfo come from?

Comment: Not a complete solution. `How you get proc info should also be simple`. hence a comment. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a hunch - your input files have the DOS carriage return line feed combination.

I added that to your file and got the same results you did.

See this question for how to remove the carriage return:

[Remove carriage return in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix)

Using the suggested `tr -d '\r'` method for removing carriage return (and might as well remove single quotes at the same time) you could do something like this:

```
echo $(tr -d "\r\'" < $PROC | awk 'NR==5{print substr($0,index($0,$2))}{print $NF}')
```

or if you need each variable assigned then something like this

```
VARS=$(tr -d "\r\'" < $PROC | awk 'NR==5{print substr($0,index($0,$2))}{print $NF}')
read PROCESS STATUS MONITOR PID UPTIME PCPU PMEM <<<$VARS
echo $PROCESS $STATUS $MONITOR $PID $UPTIME $PCPU $PMEM
```

Either way, output is

```
tomcat7 Running Monitored 3025 18d 2h 30m 30m 3.6% 0.0%
```

Comment: Thank you, I did some testing and the program that outputs the raw information for the process is putting the carriage returns in.

Comment: After each field is printed the carriage return brings the cursor back to the beginning of the line and you overwrite the output with the next field... the longest earlier fields show up, the only field guaranteed to be unmodified is the last one `0.0%`