# print the file output without ^M

Tags: linux, cat

I have a file with ^M char in it

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
HOST_SERVICE: FutureTenseContentServer:11.1.1.8.0^M
Transfer-Encoding: chunked^M
Date: Wed, 20 May 2015 02:00:04 GMT^M
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8^M
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1^M
^M
^M
^M
^M
^M
```

I need print the output of this file without ^M using cat or any linux command.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix/800644#800644 - please remember to search before posting a question, it's _highly_ likely it's been asked before :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im really so sorry for latency im using sed and pipe line it to head it will delete latest five empty lines

```
 sed 's/[\^\][M]//' file | head -n 6 > file
```

and the output will be like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HOST_SERVICE: FutureTenseContentServer:11.1.1.8.0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 20 May 2015 02:00:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
```

Comment: how to remove lines and not the spaces

Comment: The above command displaying output in a single line

Comment: In the future, be sure to provide an explanation with your answer.