# Syntax error near unexpected token `done' whis done written

Tags: linux, bash

I have a problem with the `done`. 
It says I have some typo error but I can't figure what's wrong at all.
Here is the code:

```
#./bin/bash
until [$err == 0];
do
    java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -cp lib/*:lib/uMad/*:mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:l2jfrozen-core.jar com.l2jfrozen.gameserver.GameServer
    err=$?
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting. Code should be indented.

Comment: sorry im new here :D

Comment: @barma was incorrect.  There _is_ an `until` loop in Bash: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? `until` is a recent addition.

Comment: @paddy That's why I deleted the comment. I was looking at the `bash 3.2` on my Mac, not the 4.x documentation on the web.

Comment: Give [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) a try.

Comment: @Barmar i dont know... how can i get the edition? im using ubuntu btw

Comment: @thatotherguy its says everything is ok but i still get the error

Comment: `./bin/bash --version` will tell the version number

Comment: @Barmar I am using bash 3.2.53 on my Mac, and it supports `until`.  I'm pretty sure the problem is that `#./bin/bash` should read `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @ΜάνοςΣταθόπουλος Can you update your question with the code that it says is ok, and also include the error you get?

Comment: @paddy Never mind, I was looking in the wrong part of the man page.

Comment: ive done everithing i give up it keeps saying about the unexpected done.. thank each and every one of you for your time!

Comment: Umm, did you convert the file to unix line endings, like @Barmar said?  This is actually the problem now, as per your most recent comment on my answer.

Comment: @paddy i edited the file using my linux vps using the vi command!

Comment: So, are you saying that you fixed it?

Comment: @paddy no my friend i just quit trying...

Comment: You really shouldn't get in the habit of quitting.  Try this:  Get all the correct code in a text editor and copy it.  In your terminal, type `cat > myscript.sh` and hit Enter, then paste the code in, make sure you're on a new line and press Ctrl-D.  This should ensure that you have created a new file without CRLF line endings.  Now `chmod +x myscript.sh` and run it.

Answer (score 2):

Your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line is wrong.  `#./bin/bash` will not execute bash.

It should read `#!/bin/bash`.  You are probably using a shell other than bash to invoke this script.

Also, beware that the `[$err == 0]` line expands the value of `$err`, which is probably an empty string, unless it has been exported.  If it's empty, this will result in an error, because Bash will be interpreting `[ == 0]`.

The safest approach is this:

```
unset err
until [ "$err" == "0" ];
do
    # etc...
done
```

Comment: `#./bin/bash
err=1
until [ "$err" == "0"];
do
java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -cp lib/*:lib/uMad/*:mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:l2jfrozen-core.jar com.l2jfrozen.gameserver.GameServer
err=$?
sleep 10
done` still not working :/

Comment: @ΜάνοςΣταθόπουλος Why don't you post the actual error message you're getting?

Comment: @paddy  loop.sh: line 8:syntax error near unexpected token 'done' loop.sh line 8: 'done'

Comment: @ΜάνοςΣταθόπουλος I have edited my answer, after noticing the first line of your script is wrong.

Comment: @paddy its doesnt work like that #!/bin/bash it says /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: no such file or directory

Comment: That's what you get for editing Unix files on Windows. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: @paddy You need a space before `]`

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu comes with `dos2unix` out of the box.  Simple option here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/802439/1553090

Answer (score 0):

From my experience when working with brackets and if loops, you need proper spacing and double, not single brackets. There needs to be space on each side of the double brackets with the exception of the semi-colon. Here is an example block:

```
#!/bin/bash

err=5
until [[ $err == 0 ]]; do
    ((err-=1));
    echo -e "$err\n";
    sleep 3
done
```

I do not see why the same would not apply to a do until loop.

You're probably aware but your heading has a period in it instead of a shebang.

```
#./bin/bash
```