# Improve performance of Bash loop that removes windows line endings

Tags: linux, bash, performance, sed, gawk

<sup>Editor's note: This **question was always about *loop performance***, but **the original title led some answerers - and voters - to believe it was about *how* to remove Windows line endings.**</sup>

The below bash loop below just remove the windows line endings and converts them to unix and appears to be running, but it is slow. The input files are small (4 files ranging from 167 bytes - 1 kb), and are all the same structure (list of names) and the only thing that varies is the length (ie. some files are 10 names others are 50). Is it supposed to take over 15 minutes to complete this task using a xeon processor?  Thank you :)

```
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/files/*.txt ; do
 bname=`basename $f`
 pref=${bname%%.txt}
sed 's/\r//' $f - $f > /home/cmccabe/Desktop/files/${pref}_unix.txt
done
```

**Input .txt files**

```
AP3B1
BRCA2
BRIP1
CBL
CTC1
```

**EDIT**

This is not a duplicate as I was more asking for why my `bash` loop that uses `sed` to remove windows line endings was running so slow.  I did not mean to imply how to remove them, was asking for ideas that might speed up the loop and I got many. Thank you :).  I hope this helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove carriage return in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix)

Comment: That's like asking why the water in your glass is wet. A shell loop calling sed **IS** incredibly slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 'sed' command looks wrong.  I believe the trailing `$f - $f` should simply be `$f`.  Running your script as written hangs for a very long time on my system, but making this change causes it to complete almost instantly.

Of course, the *best* answer is to use `dos2unix`, which was designed to handle this exact thing:

```
cd /home/cmccabe/Desktop/files
for f in *.txt ; do
    pref=$(basename -s '.txt' "$f")
    dos2unix -q -n "$f" "${pref}_unix.txt"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it removing the `- $f` made the loop much faster :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the utilities `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` to convert between unix and windows style line endings.

Answer (score 4):

This always works for me:

```
perl -pe 's/\r\n/\n/' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dos2unix` as stated before or use this small `sed`:

```
sed 's/\r//' file
```

Comment: True (assuming you use _GNU_ `sed`), but that command was part of the OP's question to begin with; the OP's question was not about _how_ to do it, but how to do it _faster_ in their specific scenario.

Comment: the question was totally different when i was answering it @mklement0

Comment: The original _title_ lacked focus, which is why I changed it and added a note at the top; the _gist_ of the _body_ never changed, however ("why is this so slow?") and it contained `sed 's/\r//'` from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The **key to performance** in Bash is to **avoid loops in general, and in particular those that call one or more external utilities in each iteration**.

Here is a solution that uses a ***single* GNU `awk` command**:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' '
  BEGINFILE { outFile=gensub("\\.txt$", "_unix&", 1, FILENAME) }
 { print > outFile }
' /home/cmccabe/Desktop/files/*.txt
```

- `-v RS='\r\n'` sets CRLF as the input record separator, and by virtue of leaving `ORS`, the *output* record separator at its default, `\n`, simply *printing* each input line will terminate it with `\n`.
- the `BEGINFILE` block is executed every time processing of a new input file starts; in it, `gensub()` is used to insert `_unix` before the `.txt` suffix of the input file at hand to form the output filename.
- `{print > outFile}` simply prints the `\n`-terminated lines to the output file at hand.

<sup>Note that use of a multi-char. `RS` value, the `BEGINFILE` block, and the `gensub()` function are GNU extensions to the POSIX standard.

Switching from the OP's `sed` solution to a GNU `awk`-based one was necessary in order to provide a single-command solution that is both simpler and faster.</sup>

---

Alternatively, here's a solution that relies on [`dos2unix`](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/) for conversion of Window line-endings (for instance, you can install `dos2unix` with `sudo apt-get install dos2unix` on Debian-based systems); **except for requiring `dos2unix`, it should work on most platforms** (no *GNU* utilities required):

- It uses a loop only to construct the array of filename *arguments* to pass to `dos2unix` - this should be fast, given that no call to `basename` is involved; Bash-native parameter expansion is used instead.
- then uses a *single* invocation of `dos2unix` to process *all* files.

```sh
# cd to the target folder, so that the operations below do not need to handle
# path components.
cd '/home/cmccabe/Desktop/files'

# Collect all *.txt filenames in an array.
inFiles=( *.txt )

# Derive output filenames from it, using Bash parameter expansion:
# '%.txt' matches '.txt' at the end of each array element, and replaces it
# with '_unix.txt', effectively inserting '_unix' before the suffix.
outFiles=( "${inFiles[@]/%.txt/_unix.txt}" )

# Create an interleaved array of *input-output filename pairs* to be passed
# to dos2unix later.
# To inspect the resulting array, run `printf '%s\n' "${fileArgs[@]}"`
# You'll see pairs like these:
#    file1.txt
#    file1_unix.txt
#    ...
fileArgs=(); i=0
for inFile in "${inFiles[@]}"; do
  fileArgs+=( "$inFile" "${outFiles[i++]}" )
done

# Now, use a *single* invocation of dos2unix, passing all input-output
# filename pairs at once.
dos2unix -q -n "${fileArgs[@]}"
```