# Split shell command won't split CSV file (Mac)

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, data-science

I want to use `split` to break a 5 GB CSV file into multiple files. I am testing if the `split` command works on a smaller file, so I created a CSV file named `test` with the following information:

```
Name    Age Blah
bob 12  x
sam 32  x
x   x   x
x   x   x
x   x   x
x   x   x
x   x   x
x   x   x
x   x   x
```

I run:

```
split -l 2 test2.csv
```

And I would expect five or more files created named `xaa`, `xab`, etc. Instead I am seeing one file with all the rows named `xaa`. I also tried doing it with `gsplit` and I got the same result.

Any suggestions on how to debug or how to get it to work? I am assuming this is failing silently.

Comment: The data came out wrong, but essentially I have a 3x10 csv file (3 columns, 10 rows)

Comment: It works for me here with `split` from GNU Coreutils 8.24... do you use an odd `split`?

Comment: Do you use confusing line endings? What does `wc -l` show for the input file?

Comment: Hey Ben - I use the split that is available on the mac terminal, but I also installed the GNU coreutils one and I have the same issue. This is the output for wc -l on the file: 
> wc -l test2.csv 
       0 test2.csv

Comment: This means that your shell doesn't see any line endings; try removing carriage returns as per for example this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix