# adb shell one-liner not passing output properly

Tags: android, shell, adb

I am trying to write a script that will pull any photos or videos I've taken today. Here is what the code looks like:

```
for i in $(adb shell ls -l /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/ | grep $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | awk '{ print $7 }' ) ; do adb pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/$i ~/Photos ; done
```

And here is the error I get when I run it:

```
' does not existsdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160507_012827.jpg
```

It properly grabs the name the file(s) that need to be pulled, but for some reason it doesn't pass that information to "adb pull" properly.

Do I need to do something else to "sanitize" the output of one command into the input of the other?

Comment: Hi, the keyword "sanitize" took me here. Regarding the headline "adb shell one-liner not passing output properly", this seems to be a **valid question** that seems, however, not really to be a duplicate, like its closure claims reason.
Steps to repsoduce: stuff `adb`'s output into a bash variable (`OUT=$(adb gimme sth); echo $OUT`), and see it crumbled in parts. That's the whole point here, which seems also missed by @monk's answer.

Comment: …while not being able to file a proper answer, I'll dump it here:
• some `adb` commands (or at least `adb shell`) end their output lines with 0x0d and 0x0a, and that's what is confusing us right here.
• sanitation is being done when you hand over the string to `tr`:
  `adb shell ls | tr -d '\r'`
• you can inspect the output passing it to octal dump (`od`):
  `adb shell ls | od -c`, which tells you more about included special chars
• this solution benefits largely from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/802439/211514

Answer (score -1):

why don't you just try find to list down all the files which are modified in last 24 hours and copy them to desired directory  ?

```
find ~/desired/source -mtime -1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t ~/destination/picture
```