# How to remove the CRLF(\r\n) at the end of a line in linux/unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I used

```
sed 's/\r\n$//' inputFile
```

however it didn't work. I don't know why

I also tried

```
awk '{ printf "%s", $0 }' inputFile
```

but it deletes only \n but not \r

How should I do to remove the specific combination of CRLF(\r\n) at the end of a line in linux?

P.S.

I think this is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix) given the specific condition of my question. I want the CRLF(\r\n) at the end of a line to be removed. `tr` won't work because `tr` the appearance to be removed would not necessarily at the end of the line, and the admin require not to install `dos2unix`. In my case `sed 's/\r\n$//' inputFile` is not working and I pretty much tried all the possible solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix).

By the way, with `tr`, the appearance to be removed would not necessarily at the end of the line, and `\r\n` in `tr` is a set of `\r` and `\n`. In other words, it would delete `\r` in `\r` is in the middle of the line.

Clarification:

I have one line input. I want the `\r\n` to be totally removed.

Comment: try tr -d '\a\b\r' inputFile

Comment: use dos2unix, or look at one of the hundreds of answers for the same question.

Comment: @123 I cannot use dos2unix nor install it because the admin does not allow it.

Comment: `'s/\r\n$//'` obviously doesn't work as sed is a line reader and doesn't see the newline. Also why would you ever have a carriage return in the middle of a line ?

Comment: @123 Why cannot carriage return in the middle of a line?

Comment: @MarcusThornton It can be, i just cannot see any useful reason that it would be.

Comment: Why would you want the newline to be deleted along with the carriage return? That makes no sense. A text file will be one long spliced line. For scripts that means death.

Comment: @123 I cannot define what's going to be input, and every character is possible in a line other than `\n`

Comment: Your question should be clarified a little. If you see `\r\n` in a file you want it totally removed? Or do you want it to be replaced with `\n`?

Comment: @Jens, I agree it seems like a strange request. But it does appear that the questioner does want `\r\n` to be totally removed. (Such that only *isolated* `\r` or isolated `\n` would remain)

Comment: @123 If you are doing some kind of character animation in a terminal using terminal control characters; you might have several CRs in the one line to send the cursor back so you can overwrite your previous output. This kind of thing was common in the 80's when chatting on arpanet.

Answer (score 3):

#### Answering last comment: Only one line... Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
read string <InputFile
echo -n "${string%$'\r'}"
```

Explanation: `read` will read by line, so drop naturally trailing *newline*. Then `${variable%$'\r'}` will remove **1** trailing *CR*.

Have a look at `help read` for limitation and options about doing this way:

```
printf ' foo\\x\r\t bar\r\n' > InputFile
IFS= read -r string <InputFile 
echo -n "${string%$'\r'}" | od -A n -t a -t c
      sp   f   o   o   \   x  cr  ht  sp   b   a   r
           f   o   o   \   x  \r  \t       b   a   r
```

(I use `-t c` **and** `-t a` because the second is more *readable* but don't show spaces explicitely.)

This may work under regular [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) too:

```
CR=`printf \\\r`
read string <InputFile
echo -n "${string%$CR}"
```

#### 1st answer: *End of line* and *line separator*

To whipe a *CR* at end of line, use this:

```
sed -e 's/\r$//'
```

Under Unix's `sed`, lines are *separated* by `\n`, so while you don't use `N` sed command, you may never found `\n` in **one line**.

But if you want to *merge* all your lines:

```
sed -ne ':;N;$!b;s/\r\n//g;p'
```

This will drop all `CRLF` except at very end of file. (you could drop with bash `${var%$'\r\n'}` or `head -c -2` )

```
sed -ne ':;N;$!b;s/\r\n//g;p' | head -c -2
```

Comment: Doesn't remove the newline as well.

Comment: Answer edited (anyway,  I'm not sure to understand you need... )

Comment: wrt `This will drop all CRLF except at very end of file.` - the OP has a single line so the CRLF at the end of the file is the only one he needs dropped.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, for a *one-line* input, things are very simplier... Answer edited!

Comment: The simpler solution you posted will undesirably strip all leading and trailing white space and remove all backslashes from the line. Try it on a file you create with `printf '   foo\\xbar\r\n' > InputFile`. You at least need to set IFS to null and add the -r option to read: `IFS= read -r string <InputFile`. Manipulating text with shell is never as simple as it seems like it should be because it's not what shell was designed to do (see, for example, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, have a look at `help read` and try, with your test case `printf ' foo\\xbar\r\n' > InputFile`, this: `read -r string <InputFile ; echo "${string%$'\r'}"` (under [tag:bash])

Comment: @EdMorton By using  `IFS= read -r`, the only thing [tag:bash] (v4.2+) could not handle is `$'\0'`. But I've find a way... There is a [base64 encoder](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/base64.sh.txt) written in **pure bash**. ( You may also find an [ungolfed base64 encoder](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/base64_ungolfed.sh.txt) version too ;-). It's a *proof of concept*, this work with binary files, but it's very slow!!

Answer (score 1):

Perl is reasonably portable, and well equipped to handle this.

```
perl -pe 's/\r\n//' file
```

This will leave any lone `\r` or `\n` but remove them both if they occur one after the other in this specific order.

Answer (score 1):

A completely different solution, just for fun (but it works). Assuming you've got `xxd` installed:

```
xxd -ps -c 1 inputFile |
    awk 'BEGIN {prev=""} {if ($0=="0a" && prev=="0d") {prev="skip"} else { if (prev!="skip" && prev!="") {print prev} prev=$0 } } END {if (prev!="") {print prev}}' |
    xxd -r -ps
```

Basically it translates the file into 2-digit hex per each character, then filters it with awk, looking for 2 matching lines ("0d" "0a", which is `\r\n`) in a row and skips them.

But in reality, I'd just recommend using python or perl. One of them should already be on the system. For example:

```
<inputFile python2 -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read().replace("\r\n",""))'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use **GNU** awk :

**Before:**

```
0000000   S   i   n   g   o  \n   D   i   n   g   o  \n  \r   P   i   n
0000020   g   o  \r   M   i   n   g   l   o  \r  \n   S   i   n   g   l
0000040   i  \r  \n
0000043
```

**Operation**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$"}{printf "%s",gensub(/\r\n/,"","g")}' file1 > file2  && mv file2 file1
```

**After**

```
$ od -tc file1
0000000   S   i   n   g   o  \n   D   i   n   g   o  \n  \r   P   i   n
0000020   g   o  \r   M   i   n   g   l   o   S   i   n   g   l   i
0000037
```

You may wish to change `gensub(/\r\n/,"","g")` to `gensub(/\r\n/,"\n","g")` in case you wish to replace `CRLF` with `LF`.

**Notes:**

1. You shouldn't use `print` inside awk as it will generate a `LF` at the end. Instead use `printf` with a format string.
2. I have made an edit to the answer incorporating the changes suggested by @ed-morton in **comment#1**. Also, this comment has some platform specific information which might be useful.

Comment: You should mention that's gawk/mawk-specific due to `gensub()` and setting `RS="\0"` is non-portable (instead you need to use `RS="^$"` to read in a whole file at a time) and it won't work on all platforms (e.g. cygwin) because in some the underlying C primitives gawk uses to read files will strip the `\r`s before gawk sees them so you need to set `-v BINMODE=3` to stop that from happening.

Comment: @EdMorton : I never knew we could set `RS=^$`, thankyou for this tip. Incorporating this to my answer. :D

Comment: Yes and it's guaranteed to work in any awk that accepts a multi-char RS since it means `start of string then end of string` across the whole file so the only way it can match the contents of a file is if the file is empty. So it gives you a Record Separator that cannot match any string in a non-empty file and so guarantees to read the whole file as a single record. Use of `\0` is hit-or-miss, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#gawk-split-records.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one line and you know there's definitely `\r\n` at the end, you can just use `head` and strip the last 2 bytes:

```
head -c -2 inputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and Binary Mode:

```
$ od -tc file
0000000   f   o   o       b   a   r  \r  \n
0000011

$ awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS= '1' file | od -tc
0000000   f   o   o       b   a   r
0000007
```

Here's why you need to set `BINMODE=3`:

```
$ awk '1' file | od -tc
0000000   f   o   o       b   a   r  \n
0000010

$ awk -v BINMODE=3 '1' file | od -tc
0000000   f   o   o       b   a   r  \r  \n
0000011
```

Without it on some platforms (e.g. cygqwin) gawk never even sees the `\r`, underlying C primitives remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I myself think the following method is also good if not familiar with perl or python

```
sed 's/\r$//' inputFile | awk '{printf "%s", $0}'
```

Answer (score -2):

To make unix lines out of DOS lines, you simply have to remove the carriage returns (CR). The sed command is as follows:

sed 's/\r//g' inputfile > outputfile

just give it a try.

Comment: This will do same result than `tr -d \\r` : aka: not only at end of line...