# strange behaviour when concatenate variable in ShellScript

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have this simple script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh

while read param1 param2
do
        echo "Parameter1: $param1 - 1"
        echo "Parameter2: $param2 - 2"
done <<< "$(list.ksh)"
```

The script *list.ksh* calls a Java servlet and then returns a list of servers in this style:

```
192.168.1.1 server1
192.168.1.2 server2
```

In the output of my simple script I get the following result:

```
Parameter1: 192.168.1.1 - 1
 - 2 eter2: server1
Parameter1: 192.168.1.2 - 1
 - 2 eter2: server2
```

As you can see, the output of *echo "Parameter2: $param2 - 2"* is a completely strange line. For example, the number 2 at the end of the line appears in the beginning of the output.

I have spent some much time analyzing it, but I have not gotten anything.

Do you have any idea? Maybe the output from the servelet comes with 'broken' characters?

UPDATE:

I could solve this problem after reading the comments/answer below.

I just had to replace the /r /n from the servlet with the '/n' according to the unix style:

I've made it in one line:

```
param2="$(echo $param2 | dos2unix)"
```

You can find a lot of information here: [Remove carriage return in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix)

Comment: The Java servlet is returning lines ending with carriage-return/linefeed pairs.

Comment: Thanks chepner. You were right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe the output from the servelet comes with 'broken' characters?

Not *broken* per se, but it's returning CRLFs instead of just LFs which is causing the strange output. Strip the CRs before using the data.

Comment: Sorry Ignacio, but what do you mean by 'Strip the CRs'?

Comment: I could research more about it and I understand. I had to replace the '/r /n' by just '\n', according to the unix style, and it worked. Thanks a lot. I will update the question with the solution.