# Need solution for break line issue in string

Tags: scripting, aix

I have below string which has enter character coming randomely and fields are separated by ~$~ and end with @#&.

Please help me to merge broken line into one.

In below string enter character is occured in address field (4/79A)

-------Sting----------
23510053~$~ABC~$~4313708~$~19072017~$~XYZ~$~CHINNUSAMY~$~~$~R~$~~$~~$~~$~42~$~~$~~$~~$~~$~28022017~$~
4/79A PQR Marg, Mumbai 4000001~$~TN~$~637301~$~Owns~$~RAT~$~31102015~$~12345~$~@#&

Thanks in advance.
Rupesh

Comment: I am using AIX server and Informatica to load file into target.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a (more or less) duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/802439/3595749

Note, you should ask to your client to remove the CRLF signs (rather than aplying the code below).

Nevertheless, try this:

```
cat inputfile | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/@#&/@#\&\n/g' >outputfile
```

Explanation:

- `tr` is to remove the carriage return,
- `sed` is to add it again (only when `@#&` is encountred). `s/@#&/@#\&\n/g` is to substitute "`@#&`" by "`@#&\n`" (I add a carriage return and "&" must be escaped). This applies globally (the "g" letter at the end).

Note, depending of the source (Unix or Windows), "`\n`" must be replaced by "`\r\n`" in some cases.

Comment: Dear William,

Thanks for the reply. Now my question is my first column contains numbers and at same time if address like for eg 204/7 occcurs after new line character then how should i handle that to merge line without touching first column,

For Eg:-
23510053~$~ABC~$~4313708~$~19072017~$~XYZ~$~
204/7 Mumbai~$~

Comment: I don't see your point. My code joins all the lines to provide an unique line (the tr command) then cut it (using sed) when I find "@#&". There is no link with numbers (at the beginning of a line or not). Your address will be a single field.

Comment: Try `echo "String with @#& inside" | sed 's/@#&/@#&\n/g'`. The second `&` has a special meaning: replace character with everything that is matched. I think you want `echo "String with @#& inside" | sed 's/@#&/&\n/g'`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed. You just can apply an "\" before "&" to escape the special character. I edited the answer accordingly.