# Gerrit - error: found carriage return (CR) character in file: gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gerrit

I am building a Spring-Boot Application (2.1.4.RELEASE) and I am creating a Gradle Wrapper for it using

> gradle clean wrapper

My gradle version is 5.4

What is happening is that when I try to push my changes into Gerrit I am getting this error:

> remote: error: found carriage return (CR) character in file:
>   gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar remote: error: found carriage return
>   (CR) character in file: gradlew.bat

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (Windows 10 Native Client)

I tried in my Windows machine and the problem is the same, I tried to switch to Gradle 4 and the same problem happens, Gradle 3 can't compile my application anymore so it is not an option.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Gerrit server is using the plugin [uploadvalidator](https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/plugins_uploadvalidator) or other similar one. This plugin has a feature to reject files with carriage return (CR) in the line endings (search for "rejectWindowsLineEndings" [here](https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/plugins_uploadvalidator/blob/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md)).

To resolve this issue remove the carriage returns in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar and gradlew.bat files. See how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix).