# SED to replace strings containing CR LF

Tags: sed, replace, newline

I am trying to replace a string that contains CR and LF in the text of a file.

So the input file

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
```

Becomes

```
abcd
zxgh
ijkl
```

literally I wish the string "cd + CR + LF + ef" to be replaced with "cd + CR + LF + zx".
I have tried

```
sed -e 's/cd\red/cd\rzx/g' file
sed -e 's/cd\r\ned/cd\r\nzx/g' file
```

without success

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove carriage return in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to Perl.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/cd\r\nef/cd\r\nzx/' file
```

Or with GNU sed:

```
sed '/cd\r$/{N;s/cd\r\nef/cd\r\nzx/}' file
```

Output:

```
abcd
zxgh
ijkl
```

Comment: thank you. i also has to use the command `unix2dos file` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, you can do it as follows:

```
sed '/cd\r$/N;s/cd\r\nef/cd\r\nzx/' file
```

Comment: thank you. i also has to use the command `unix2dos file` to make it work.