# how to send contents of a file to curl as parameter

Tags: bash, ubuntu, curl, httprequest, file-read

I am measuring performance of different URL's that are stored in a file

##### Url.txt looks like:

---

http:://localhost:8080/bankDetail 
 
http://localhost:8080/bankAccount 
 
http://localhost:8081/hi

---

##### Shell Script

```
while read line 
do 
    echo $line #content printed here fine 
    curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s $line

done < url.txt
```

But the curl command returns time_total = 0.00000s as if it is **not** working properly.

Comment: Try adding `-S` (uppercase "S") to curl's options to see if there are any error messages. Also, confirm that the input file uses LF line endings (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix). Also also, quote parameter expansions: `$line` --> `"$line"`

Comment: @rowboat Thank you, The issue was the carriage returns. I removed them and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Used this command to remove carriage returns from the file.

```
tr -d '\r' < url.txt > new_url.txt
```

Then used new_url.txt in the code and it works now.